# tf-idf for text cluster-analysis

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I would like to group small texts included in a column, `df['Texts']`, from a dataframe. 
An example of sentences to analyse are as follows:

```
    Texts

  1 Donald Trump, Donald Trump news, Trump bleach, Trump injected bleach, bleach coronavirus.
  2 Thank you Janey.......laughing so much at this........you have saved my sanity in these mad times. Only bleach Trump is using is on his heed 
  3 His more uncharitable critics said Trump had suggested that Americans drink bleach. Trump responded that he was being sarcastic.
  4 Outcry after Trump suggests injecting disinfectant as treatment.
  5 Trump Suggested 'Injecting' Disinfectant to Cure Coronavirus?
  6 The study also showed that bleach and isopropyl alcohol killed the virus in saliva or respiratory fluids in a matter of minutes.
```

Since I know that TF-IDF is useful for clustering, I have been using the following lines of code (by following some previous questions in the community):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import re
import string

def preprocessing(line):
    line = line.lower()
    line = re.sub(r"[{}]".format(string.punctuation), " ", line)
    return line

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocessing)
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(all_text)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(tfidf) # the number of clusters could be manually changed
```

However, since I am considering a column from a dataframe, I do not know how to apply the above function. 
Could you help me with it?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, as you already have the code correct as far as I can tell. Have you tried `tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Texts'])` to see the results?

Comment: thank you so much @G.Anderson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def preprocessing(line):
    line = line.lower()
    line = re.sub(r"[{}]".format(string.punctuation), " ", line)
    return line

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocessing)
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Texts'])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(tfidf)
```

You just need to replace all_text with your df. It'd be nice to build a pipeline first then apply vectorizer and Kmeans all at the same time.

Also for getting more precise result more preprocessing of your text is never a bad idea. In addition, however I dont think lowering the text is a good idea since you naturally remove a good feature for style of writing(If we consider you want to find the author or assign author to a group) but for getting the sentiment of sentences yeah it's better to lower.

Comment: Thank you so much Ehsan. I received this output: `KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
    n_clusters=2, n_init=10, n_jobs=None, precompute_distances='auto',
    random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)`. How could I get 'useful' and readable information? I cannot understand what the output means. I would have expected some lists or some information more 'visual'

Comment: Well, in fact it is a heavy topic . Let me see if I can find you a useful link with example to understand but in the meanwhile try to do the clustering for a range of number of clusters then plot it and find the elbow pattern. That point would be the best number of clusters that you can have. And for future data you can predict the class of your text based on the best kmeans model that you have.

Comment: Could you please share some information on how to do clustering from that output? I would have expected something more graphical, like information that I could have plotted but in this case I think it would be impossible to do it. Also, you mentioned about predict the class: how could I predict it? Could you please provide me an example? If you think it would be better to open a new question, I will do it

Comment: In this link you can find in depth example of how to use kmeans for clustering and elbow technique. https://github.com/JishaDSND/Udacity/blob/master/Arvato%20Project%20Workbook_final.ipynb

Comment: Great! Thank you so much @Ehsan!